# twitter typahead.js results links to url

Tags: javascript, twitter-typeahead

I'm using twitter typeahead.js for the first time and im trying to do something that I guess is quite simple but i cant figure out how. I want users to be forwarded to a specific URL by on the typeahead suggested list results. I want to use multiple datasets and the urls to be stored in JSON files.

For example (using adapted typeahead.js example code):

CSS:

```
#multiple-datasets .league-name {
  margin: 0 20px 5px 20px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="multiple-datasets">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="NBA and NHL teams">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/nba.json'
});

var nhlTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/nhl.json'
});

nbaTeams.initialize();
nhlTeams.initialize();

$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
  highlight: true
},
{
  name: 'nba-teams',
  displayKey: 'team',
  source: nbaTeams.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
  }
},
{
  name: 'nhl-teams',
  displayKey: 'team',
  source: nhlTeams.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="league-name">NHL Teams</h3>'
  }
});
```

NHL.JSON:

```
[{ "team": "Dallas Stars", "url": "stars.html" },{ "team": "Los Angeles Kings", "url": "kings.html" },{ "team": "Phoenix Coyotes", "url": "coyotes.html" },{ "team": "San Jose Sharks", "url": "sharks.html" }]
```

NBA.JSON:

```
[{ "team": "Boston Celtics", "url": "celtics.html" },{ "team": "Dallas Mavericks", "url": "mavericks.html" },{ "team": "Brooklyn Nets", "url": "nets.html" },{ "team": "Houston Rockets", "url": "rockets.html" }
```

So if a user types 'rockets' then they can click on the 'Houston Rockets' suggestion from the list, and will be directed to rockets.html. Im not sure how to get the javascript to turn the suggestions into the corresponding links from the JSON.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead has an event typeahead:selected, which indicates the selected item from within the autocomplete results, try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var check = false;

jQuery('input[name="searchInputID"]').typeahead({
    name: 'autocomplete',
    remote: '/typeahead//autocomplete/%QUERY',
    limit: 20,
    valueKey: 'name',
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum) {
    check = true;
    jQuery('input[name="searchInputID"]').val(datum.name);
    window.location = datum.url;
});
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your reply. I cant really figure out how to use this though. Can you post an example? thanks again.